# jQuery Isotope Searchable Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have an Isotope Gallery and I would like to add a live search function, meaning as a person types a word the gallery will start to auto filter.

1) Is this possible with Isotopes?

2) If so, how do I do this?

Note: I have searched and not found anything online for this.

Here is what one item in my gallery looks like:

```
<div class="element hybrid numbers-filter" data-category="hybrid">
  <p class="type">H</p>
  <h2 class="name">303</h2>
  <p class="strain-info">No Info Available</p>
  <p class="review"><a class="fancy_button review-form-lb" href="#review-form-lightbox"><span style="background-color: #000;">Review Strain</span></a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reading about Isotope 2 there was a [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wfaGu) with this exact feature!

Here is the code making it work in the event the link above goes down:

Note: This is not my code but the code example.

***HTML***

```
<input type="text" id="quicksearch" placeholder="Search" />
<div class="isotope">
  <!-- ISOTOPE CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
```

***JS***

```
$( function() {
// quick search regex
var qsRegex;

// init Isotope
var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  filter: function() {
    return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
  }
});

// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
  qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
  $container.isotope();
}) );

});

// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
var timeout;
return function debounced() {
  if ( timeout ) {
    clearTimeout( timeout );
  }
  function delayed() {
    fn();
    timeout = null;
  }
  setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to have something specifically built-in for that purpose, however since the `filter` function seems to allow any kind of selector that jQuery supports, you could build something around that using the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

E.g.

```
$('#container').isotope({ filter: ':contains("search text")' });
```